# Debugging Tkinter code gives "RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop"

Tags: python, tkinter, visual-studio-code

I know the internet is full of questions about Tkinter raising "RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop". But almost all of them discuss about how to run threads in parallel.
I don't (at least I guess that).
My problem is: the code runs completely fine stand-alone. But as soon as a GUI is shown in debugging mode it's only a question of seconds until this Runtime Error occurs. My best guess: the debugger itself runs in a parallel thread?!?
If I am right: what can I do about it? How can I reliably debug code that uses TKinter?

Versions:

- Visual Studio Code 1.68
- Python 3.9.13

Minimal example:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


class GUI(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        # Initialize.
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.N + tk.E + tk.S + tk.W)
        # Create radio buttons
        self.button = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='Yes', value=True)
        self.button.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.E)
        self.button2 = ttk.Radiobutton(self, text='No', value=False)
        self.button2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=tk.E)
        # Put an OK button to the bottom right corner.
        self.w_ok = ttk.Button(self, text='OK', command=self._exit)
        self.w_ok.grid(row=100, column=2, sticky=tk.SE)
    def _exit(self):
        self.master.destroy()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    gui = GUI(root)
    gui.mainloop()
```

On request of @MingJie-MSFT here is the launch.json of Vscode:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Aktuelle Datei",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "autoReload": {"enable": true}
        }
    ]
}
```

... and the error report:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Variable.__del__ at 0x000001B5B67451F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 363, in __del__
    if self._tk.getboolean(self._tk.call("info", "exists", self._name)):
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
```

Comment: It worked for me. I don't see nothing wrong.

Comment: It works for me as well. Can you provide your launch.json and error report?

Comment: Thanks for testing! Well, this is the hitch with this error - some days it works just fine and some days I get this error every single time the code is debugged.
Launch.json and error report will be added above...

Answer (score 1):

> RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
> Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread

1.You can set the thread to a Daemon:

```
t = threading.Thread(target=your_func)
t.setDaemon(True)
t.start()
```

2.There actually is a thread-safe alternative to Tkinter, [mtTkinter](https://github.com/RedFantom/mtTkinter).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I can not directly feedback if it works since the error comes and goes. But to be sure: which function should I set to the deamon? Everything I code (so basically the main()) or just the GUI call?
The mtTkinter package is already known but (1) is does not seem to be developed anymore (so I am afraid it will be obsolete one time) and (2) in some projects I am not able to add packages but have to stick with what an ordinary Python ships. So for some this might be a solution, for me not however :(